# How to select SVG paths with class names in javascript

Tags: javascript, css, svg

I have an SVG and would like to change the style of an element when another element is hovered. In this example, when I hover over "ring_three_fill" then I would live the styling of "ring_three_border" to change. I tried two ways: css and javascript. Both methods did not work. Since it's not working in css, is there a way to select paths with a class name in javascript that change on hover?

```
<path id="ring_three_fill" class="ring-fill hide" opacity="0.5" fill="#66BCEA" d="M563.6,255.3c0.1,0,0.2,0,0.2,0c0-3.5,0.3-7.1-0.1-10.6
    c-1.3-12-5.6-22.9-13.1-32.4c-10.5-13.3-18.5-28-23.4-44.3c-1.6-5.4-3.7-10.6-6.1-15.6c-5-10.8-11.9-19.9-23.2-24.8"/>
<path id="ring_three_border" class="ring-border hide" opacity="0.5" fill="#66BCEA" d="M537.4,265.2c-0.9-12.9-5-24.5-12.5-35.1"/>
```

CSS:

```
path.ring-fill:hover path.ring-border {
            transform: scale(1.2,1.2);
        }
```

Javascript:

```
var fill = document.getElementsByClassName("ring_fill");
        fill.onmouseover = function() {
            document.getElementsByClassName("ring-border").attr("style", "transform: scale(1.2,1.2);")
        };
```

Comment: You are mixing jQuery and JavaScript wrongly. What is the difference between `fills` and `fill`? is that a typo?

Comment: @Sergio sorry that was a typo.

Comment: Try with `$('.ring_fill').on('mouseover', function(){ $(this).attr("style", "transform: scale(1.2,1.2);"); });`does it work?

Comment: @Sergio I would like to do this in pure javascript, no jQuery.

Comment: Ok, is there more than one element with that class? or is it just one?

Comment: jQuery method did not work.
Please look at my codepen to see what I am trying to do: http://codepen.io/nsohail92/pen/LpwBgM

Answer (score 0):

I supose this is what you want. With plain JavaScript.

```
var proximity = 2;
var steps = parseInt(5 / (proximity * 2), 10);

function sortPaths(list) {
    var sizes = [].map.call(list, function (path) {
        return {
            el: path,
            length: path.getTotalLength()
        };
    });
    return sizes.sort(function (a, b) {
        return a.length > b.length;
    }).map(function (path) {
        return path.el;
    });
}

function reset(from, to, arr) {
    for (var i = from; i < to; i++) {
        arr[i].setAttribute("style", "transform: scale(1,1);");
    }
}

function attach(rings, i) {
    var start = proximity * -1;
    return function () {
        for (var j = start; j < proximity; j++) {
            var el = rings[i + j];
            if (!el) continue;
            var step = (j == 0 ? 13 : 10 + (j / 3 * 4));
            var transform = ['transform: scale(', ',', ');'].join(step / 10);
            el.setAttribute("style", transform);
        }
        reset(i + proximity, rings.length, rings);
    }
}

var rings = sortPaths(document.querySelectorAll('path.ring-border'));
for (var i = 0; i < rings.length; i++) {
    rings[i].addEventListener('mouseenter', attach(rings, i));
    rings[i].addEventListener('mouseleave', function () {
        this.setAttribute("style", "transform: scale(1,1);");
    });
}
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2nm5j0jq/

You might need to configure it a bit more, but that should be very near what you want.